# Deploying a Mean Stack App, Apache?

Tags: angularjs, apache, deployment, express, nginx

I am starting to learn Angular and I am employing a MEAN stack. The grey area in my mind is when my angular app is finished and ready to deploy on a server.

Would I still need to use Apache of Nginx to route a domain or subdomain to my app?

I guess the node/express.js is my main question. I have used it when working locally, but when deploying would that run my app on the server side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Node and your app on the server as-is, single-threaded...provided you took care of telling DNS where to reach the app.

To riff off your nginx question...here are a few of other deployment/config questions that you may consider:

- **server crashes:** sooooo...node isn't at 1.0 yet and apps sometimes do unexpected things and die.  tools like `forever`, `supervisor` and similar things can auto-restart the server.
- **logging:** tools like morgan, winston and more can provide logging so you can see what was happening on the server before big events (everybody hit the same page, the server crashed every time page XYZ was hit, etc)
- **load balancing:** a node server is single-threaded, single-instance. if you have a super busy site or you are stuck with synchronous stuff (blah!) you'll want to consider how to spin up multiple node instances.  nginx and node clustering would be things to consider, but if your app is small, this is probably not a priority over handling crashes and logging

Comment: Thank you for the questions to consider you bring up some great points

Comment: Are there any best practices for load balancing with Node? I have lightly skimmed over methods of doing this, but it does seem complex. Do you recommend anything?

Comment: There are a ton of variables, so there isn't a single answer. If you are just starting with a new app, I wouldn't sweat it until you start to max the first server. If you use one of the many hosting providers (Heroku, Modulus, Azure, etc), they do some of the front end for you...it's an option to consider.